# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'add_config_file_help'

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm trying to run Retrieval-eval.py, but I am encountering the following error:

```
 TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'add_config_file_help'
```

I'm using get_sim_score() method to compute similarity score from another directory while going through that method it goes to argparser.py here i got this error showed above. This is my argparser.py here in class NeonArgparser() im encountering that error. Can anyone help me with this error?

```
**class NeonArgparser(configargparse.ArgumentParser):**
    """
    Setup the command line arg parser and parse the
    arguments in sys.arg (or from configuration file).  Use the parsed
    options to configure the logging module.*emphasized text*

    Arguments:
        desc (String) : Docstring from the calling function. This will be used
                        for the description of the command receiving the
                        arguments.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._PARSED = False
        self.work_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'nervana')
        if 'default_config_files' not in kwargs:
            kwargs['default_config_files'] = [os.path.join(self.work_dir,
                                                           'neon.cfg')]
        if 'add_config_file_help' not in kwargs:
            # turn off the auto-generated config help for config files since it
            # referenced unsettable config options like --version
            kwargs['add_config_file_help'] = False

        self.defaults = kwargs.pop('default_overrides', dict())
        super(NeonArgparser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # ensure that default values are display via --help
        self.formatter_class = configargparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter

        self.setup_default_args()
```

Here is the exception trace, Please have a look.

```
    (ronin) pratyusha@pratyusha-Q304UAK:~/Projects/ronin$ python Retrieval-Eval.py
No handlers could be found for logger "gensim.models.doc2vec"
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
Can you suggest a spa for us?
Are transport facilities available here?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 484, in <module>
    e = evaluate(dialogue, dtype="str", concept_weight=1.0, task_weight=0)
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 248, in evaluate
    retrieval2 = get_skipsim_matches(selected=questions, dtype="str", conceptW=concept_weight, taskW=task_weight)  #HERE !!!!!!!!!!!!!
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 446, in get_skipsim_matches
    conceptDictionary = get_skipsim_concept_dictionary(selected[1:], dtype)   
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 464, in get_skipsim_concept_dictionary
    scores = get_list_skipsim_scores(selected, dialogue, dtype)   
  File "Retrieval-Eval.py", line 430, in get_list_skipsim_scores
    score = st.get_sim_score(q1, q2)    
  File "/home/pratyusha/Desktop/neon/examples/skipthought/inference.py", line 132, in get_sim_score
    a = self.get_sentence_vec(text1)
  File "/home/pratyusha/Desktop/neon/examples/skipthought/inference.py", line 50, in get_sentence_vec
    parser = NeonArgparser(__doc__)
  File "/home/pratyusha/.virtualenvs/ronin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neon/util/argparser.py", line 80, in __init__
    super(NeonArgparser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'add_config_file_help'
```

Thank You    `

Comment: Don't dump code without any explanation of what your issue is.

Comment: @chrisz I  am trying to perform retrieval task using skipthougt model in a case based reasoning system. that retrieval task is going well but im getting this error while producing results                                                                                                                          THANK YOU

Comment: Edit your question with all relevant information including a complete exception trace. Don't respond in the comments.

Comment: @MadPhysicist i have posted a screenshot can you help me with this error. this is kind of emergency.

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Post text as text, and format it properly. And learn to manage your time better. I will help you when you ask a proper question containing all the necessary information.

Comment: Also, read your error messages carefully. They're quite clear if you take the time to think about them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you for your suggestions, actually im new to stackoverflow. So I apologize for not posting my question clearly. but i could not understand that error message

Comment: It's fine to be new and to learn new things. That's why I'm taking the time to guide you towards writing a proper question. Please don't expect to get help without taking the effort to follow my suggestions just because you are new.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you help me with this error?

Comment: The error means that you are passing `add_config_file_help` as both a positional and a keyword argument. Please get in the habit of using Google first and asking on stack overflow last. Also do not expect me to slog through two massive files of code to track down your error. That is your job. I'll be glad to help you when you have a minimal example illustrating your issue. Until then, I have to vote to close.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks a lot I finally solved that issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mainly due to a bug in latest version of *ConfigArgParse*.
For now to get you unblocked please install some version other than latest by running this command:

`pip install --no-cache-dir ConfigArgParse>=0.10.0,<0.13.0`

If you are running from within a shell you may want to escape some chars:

`pip install --no-cache-dir ConfigArgParse\>\=0.10.0,\<0.13.0`

and now you should be able to run the example:
`

```
$ python examples/mnist_mlp.py -b cpu
Epoch 0   [Train |████████████████████|  469/469  batches, 0.27 cost, 1.39s]
Epoch 1   [Train |████████████████████|  469/469  batches, 0.20 cost, 1.43s]
Epoch 2   [Train |████████████████████|  469/469  batches, 0.18 cost, 1.44s]
Epoch 3   [Train |████████████████████|  468/468  batches, 0.14 cost, 1.44s]
Epoch 4   [Train |████████████████████|  468/468  batches, 0.12 cost, 1.45s]
Epoch 5   [Train |████████████████████|  468/468  batches, 0.11 cost, 1.45s]
Epoch 6   [Train |████████████████████|  468/468  batches, 0.11 cost, 1.44s]
Epoch 7   [Train |████████████████████|  468/468  batches, 0.09 cost, 1.45s]
Epoch 8   [Train |████████████████████|  468/468  batches, 0.09 cost, 1.50s]
Epoch 9   [Train |████████████████████|  468/468  batches, 0.08 cost, 1.44s]
2018-02-27 18:49:54,287 - neon - DISPLAY - Misclassification error = 2.5%`
```